# Show two images on launchscreen iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, swift4.2

I need to display two images in the centre of my launch screen one after the other. Might be a newbie question but I can't seem to figure out how to do it. I know it's against apple HCI guidelines, but it's the client's requirement so any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can Achieve this by doing these steps:
1) Add first image in launch screen
2) Create splash screen viewcontroller which contains second image
3) Make splash screen viewcontroller as initial view controller from storyboard.

additionally You can add flow logic in splash screen viewcontroller like display login screen after splash screen or home screen after splash screen etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SwiftUI, it is not possible to add two image views on launch screen. I have tried to make image smaller, to change type, to insert splash screen... Instead, if you, for example, have two images (one for background, and one for logo) you can insert imageView for background image and button for logo image.  In "Attributes inspector" for UIButton, in the field "Image" you can chose logo image. After that only disable interaction with button and you are set to go.